# Get first file in directory

Tags: c#, vb.net

This is probably pretty basic, but I'm trying to find out how I can find the first file in a directory?

For example, if I've got these lines of code

```
Dim di as New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Test")
Dim aryFi as IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.txt")
```

I can see that the aryFi contains a list of all files, but I need only one and I need the full path of that one file. How can I get it?

Comment: 1st by what sort method? Alphabetically?

Comment: Hi, the files are all the same, so it doesn't matter which file really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dim firstFullPath = di(1).FullPath
```

(I'm assuming VB.NET is still 1-based. Otherwise `di(0).FullPath`.)

For production code you should check that the array isn't empty before trying this.

Comment: Thanx, this is great! :) Jon Skeet to the resque :)
Btw, I just saw a funny post this other day from StackOverflow where is says that "even Jon Skeet can't parse HTML using regular expressions" :) Funny :)